# Airflow policy: How to define and configure one?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to define an airflow policy but I'm lost and there's not that much documentation. I create a file inside $HOME_AIRFLOW/config called airflow_settings.py. Inside I have the policy that tries to change the queue of a failed task. The policy doesn't work. Does anybody have an example?

By the way I'm using airflow 1.10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file should be named `airflow_local_settings.py`, and it should be inside your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Should I import anything in the policy? or just define like: def policy(Task_Instance):

Comment: No need to import anything (afaik) unless you need to use something explicitly. you can work only on the `task_instance` if that works for you.